# Find all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and $\mathbb{Z}_9^\times$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Can you please help me in this question:

> Find all the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ and $\mathbb{Z}_9^\times$.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have I interpreted your question correctly? Also, just to be certain, are you using $$\mathbb{Z}_n$$
to mean the integers modulo $n$, and
$$\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$$
to mean the unit group of the integers modulo $n$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** By [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) the order of every subgroup divides the order of the group.

Answer (score 2):

For your first group $\,\mathbb Z_7$.

We know that the order of $\,\mathbb Z_7$ is $7$, and $7$ is prime.

Recall:

> *Any group* of *prime order* has no *proper, non-trivial* subgroups: the only subgroups of ANY group of prime order are the group itself, and the trivial group.

And in $(\mathbb Z_n, +)$ the trivial group is $\{0\}$, the identity. This can be shown *without* knowing the theorem of Lagrange, though it follows immediately from the theorem.

- Also good to know, but not needed here: Every group of prime order $p$ is *cyclic* and isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z_p, +)$.

---

For $(\mathbb Z_9, \cdot)$, we have the multiplicative group of integers, the unit group of integers, modulo $9$.

Its elements are all integers $n$ such that $1\leq n\lt 9$ such that $\gcd(n, 9) = 1$ (all positive integers less than $9$ that are co-prime to $9$). So $\mathbb Z_9^\times = \{1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8\}$ and hence has order $6$.

By the Theorem of Lagrange, we know that the only possible candidates for proper subgroups,  will be of order $2$ or $3$.

As I see Peter noted: there is exactly one group of order $2$.

I'll suggest one candidate for a subgroup of order $3$: $\{1, 4, 7\}$, noting that $4\cdot 7 \equiv 1\pmod 9$. Does it satisfy the criteria of being a subgroup? Can you find any other subgroups of order $3$ that meet the criteria? If not, you are done

Comment: "[W]e can rule out a group of order $2$." To me, $\pm 1 \pmod 9 = \{1,8\}$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z^\times_9$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Bbb Z_7$ is cyclic of prime order, what can you say about  a subgroup $G=\langle a\rangle$ for some $a\in \Bbb Z_7$. Recall that in this case we must have $|a|\mid 7$.

On the other hand, $\Bbb Z_9^\times$ is $\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}$. It has order $6$, so any *proper* subgroup has to have order $2$ or $3$.

**HINT** If the subgroup is of order two, say $\{1,a\}$, then we must have $a^2=1$. There is only one elements in $\Bbb Z_9^\times$ with such property. Thus there is only one subgroup of order two. If a subgroup has order three, say $\{1,a,b\}$, then $ab=1$, for if $ab=a$, $b=1$, and the same with $a$. Can you work something out of this?

**ADD** As per $\Bbb Z_p$ for $p$ prime, we can state:

> A nontrivial group $G$ has no proper subgroups if and only if $G$ is finite of prime order (and thus cyclic).

Answer (score 1):

Or by using GAP, you get the second group's subgroups:

[image]

Comment: +1 You'll have to teach me how to use GAP...I did so awhile back, but didn't know how to exploit its power.

Comment: @amWhy: You and Peter, in fact, killed the problem. ;-) I just noted a small program which might be helpful for the next. I am at your service.

Answer (score 0):

Sub groups of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ are

$H_1 = \{0\}$

$H_2 = \mathbb{Z}_7$

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb Z_9^\times$ is a group (under multiplication).